# Leetcode 550 Game Play Analysis IV My solution with windows function is stuck at the last step

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to solve this Leetcode Database problem #550 - Game Play Analysis IV.
Giving below the url to the problem for anyone to access without having to login to leetcode:

```
https://code.dennyzhang.com/game-play-analysis-iv
```

I tried to solve the problem using windows function which is different from the approach given in the solution of the above link.

My query in PostgreSQL:

```
select count(distinct player_id) from
(select player_id, 
lag(event_date,1) over (partition by player_id order by event_date) as prev,
event_date,
lead(event_date,1) over (partition by player_id order by event_date) as next
from activity) t
where t.event_date - t.prev = 1 or t.next - t.event_date = 1
```

My query is correctly giving me the count of players who satisfy the requirement.
However, I am facing challenge in representing the result as a fraction to the total number of distinct players present.

Any guidance would be of much help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use common table expression to get the output from your query and use it to calculate fraction as follows:

```
;with cte as (
  select count(distinct player_id) as cnt 
  from
  ( select player_id, 
    lag(event_date,1) over (partition by player_id order by event_date) as prev,
    event_date,
    lead(event_date,1) over (partition by player_id order by event_date) as next
    from activity
   ) t
  where t.event_date - t.prev = 1 or t.next - t.event_date = 1
)
select round(cte.cnt/count( distinct activity.player_id),2) as "fraction" 
from activity, cte
```